# Is there a way to dynamically populate a dropdown depending on the value of other cells?

Tags: google-sheets, data-validation

Is there a way to populate a dropdown list differently depending on the values of another cell? For example, the dropdown in A2 contains *Movies* and *Sports*. I want the dropdown in A3 to have *Horror* and *Romance* in its dropdown selection if I select *Movies* in A2 and *Baseball* and *Basketball* if I select *Sports*

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make the second validation list an if/then statement dependent on the answer to the first one.

`=if(A1="Movies","Horror","Baseball")`

`=if(A1="Movies","Romance","Basketball")`

An example is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AjUWz7mkWZSZ4-3Lt77j8_h3v_dHz-Kgso5a4zYEmKQ/edit#gid=0).

Comment: can i add 2 data validations to a single cell?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes. Lay it out in the same way and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: ahhh, i see now, sorry, haha, is the D column necessary to act as a database of some sort? or is there a way to integrate the whole thing into A2? this is definitely helpful though:)

Comment: sorry for asking so many questions, but while i have you here, can i do a data validation on A2 with the range a-b if A1 has "Yes" and the range c-d if A1 has "No"?

so if i put "Yes" in A1, A2 will ask for the values 0-10, but will ask for the values 11-20 if i put "No" in A1

thanks

Comment: I updated the example to reflect that using the same technique. I maybe able to do the other piece with some scripting but am heading to sleep for now. You can check out the [scripting validation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#newDataValidation()) if you want to give it a shot or here is [another similar question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744547/how-do-you-do-dynamic-dependent-drop-downs-in-google-sheets)